# Give access to a folder for a specific person using email

Tags: linux, users, shared-folders

I have a processing machine that is running on Linux and is used by many people. This machine has only one user where people using this machine can login and use the machine. What I wanted to do is to create a folder for each person where they can place their data and it will be secured using their email and password for example, so that others will have access to everything except other people private folders. So for example in ~/Documents there will be a folder for each person where only this person can access the content of this folder. Any advice?

Comment: you need a separate account for each user.

Comment: @cas but they use everything in the machine all together, how I can do this? Like I want them to see and use everything in the machine (applications,....) except folders of other people.

Comment: if you only have one user account, there is no way for the system to know who is using it at any given moment.  The best you could do without individual user accounts is an "honour system" and hope that other people don't sneak a look at someone else's private files.

Comment: @cas What is an "honour system"?

Comment: an honour system is where you trust to the honour of people not to do bad things.  with predictable results.

Comment: @cas  Oh okay, so it's not a technical thing it's a moral thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a separate account for each user.  There's no way around this if you want users to be able to have private files.

If you also need a shared documents folder (as well as each users private folder), then create a unix group, add all users to that group, use `chgrp` to set the shared directory's group-owner to that group, and `chmod g=rwsX` on the directory to enable all group members to read, write, cd into, list files, etc.  This `s` (sticky bit) in the `g=rwsX`  chmod mode makes sure that all files and subdirectories created in the shared directory are also owned by that group.

For example:

```
addgroup --group shared    # create group called 'shared'

addgroup username shared   # add username to group 'shared'. repeat for every user

mkdir /home/shared
chgrp shared /home/shared
chmod g=rwsX /home/shared
```

You can either create a symlink in each users' home directory pointing to `/home/shared` (and create one in `/etc/skel` too so newly created users get it by default), or just tell everyone to look for shared files in `/home/shared`.

Comment: what if I had 100 users? I'll make 100 user accounts on the machine?

Comment: yes.  alternatively, make accounts for those who want private space, and a shared account for everyone else.   BTW, it's not terribly difficult to script the process of adding accounts, just use the right command line options to `adduser` so that it doesn't have to prompt for everything (and use `--disabled-password` - you can set the passwords later in the script with `chpasswd`).   For passwords, generate a file containing a line 'username:random_password' for each user and pipe that into `chpasswd`.  Then give each user their  personal password and tell them to change it ASAP.

Comment: Thank you, I've upvoted your answer. Is it possible to update your answer with a script that process adding accounts? As I'm not good with commands and scripts. Thanks again in advance

Comment: here's an example: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79912/7696.   You'll need a list of username and real names (for the GECOS field).  You also need a list of usernames and passwords.  You can generate random passwords with tools like `pwgen` or `makepasswd`.  Your script will need to loop around the `adduser` command, once for each user.  You can just pipe the entire file with username:password into `chpasswd` in one go.   If you have trouble implementing that, post a **new** question showing what you've done so far and what you're having trouble with.

Comment: btw, you'll also need to distribute the passwords to the users.  one simple way is to print the username:password list with a few lines between each user, and cut it into small strips, one for each user with their login details.  remind them to change their password as soon as the log in.  or you can force that with `chage -d 0 username` (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/173708/how-do-i-force-a-user-to-change-a-password-at-the-first-time-login-using-ssh)